# How do I stop player from rotating after touching a wall?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have started making a 3d game, and I have my player and a wall object and a floor set up. Whenever my player object touches the wall though it rotates as though falling backwards and just continues to rotate forever.

I have tried enabling freeze rotation of both the y and the z on the rigidbody of the player (x rotation is obviously needed and is not the problem) and have tried a couple of different things with either making the wall static. changing it to kinematic etc and I cannot find a way to stop the player rotating after touching the wall.

Player movement is controlled in fixed update as shown:

````
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        m_Movement.Set(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
        m_Movement.Normalize();

        bool hasHorizontalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(horizontal, 0f);
        bool hasVerticalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(vertical, 0f);
        bool isWalking = hasHorizontalInput || hasVerticalInput;
        bool isShiftKeyDown = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);

        if (hasHorizontalInput || hasVerticalInput)
        {
            if (isShiftKeyDown)
            {
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsIdle", false);
                m_AudioSource.clip = running;
               
            } else
           
            {
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsRunning", false);
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
                m_Animator.SetBool("IsIdle", false);
                m_AudioSource.clip = walking;
                
            }
        } else
        {
            m_Animator.SetBool("IsRunning", false);
            m_Animator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
            m_Animator.SetBool("IsIdle", true);
        }
          
       
        //m_Animator.SetBool("IsWalking", isWalking);

        Vector3 desiredForward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, m_Movement, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
        m_Rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredForward);

        if (isWalking)
        {
            if (!m_AudioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                m_AudioSource.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_AudioSource.Stop();
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Angular Drag in the rigidbody of the player.

Comment: I have increased the angular drag to no avail. What I ended up doing which seems to have solved the issue is in fixedupdate, before all the handlers for when there is input detected (so while there is no input detected or while nothing has been done with the input) is changed the Rigidbody velocity to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the problem might be in the these lines:

```
Vector3 desiredForward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, m_Movement, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
m_Rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredForward);
```

Here you are rotating `transform.forward` towards `m_Movement`, but if i understand how your code works correctly, this will cause it to spin forever. Try removing these lines and see what happens. Also, on which axis is it spinning?

Comment: These lines of code are what is moving the player character towards the button press - ie, w forward, a backward etc - removing these lines stops the character from moving. This rotation is along the Y axis and the problem axis is along the x axis.

Comment: @Bluesombre ah alright, seems you found a fix anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem, what I have found to fix this is inside FixedUpdate, before any calls are made to use input, is set the Rigidbody.velocity to 0.